# minimise the trace of a matrix over all column permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, trace

I have a 10x10 **positive symmetric matrix**, I need to find the optimal permutation of the columns in order to **minimise the trace**. I can't try all permutations because that would be a 10! problem. Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876711/maximize-the-trace-of-a-matrix-by-permuting-its-rows?rq=1.

Comment: It's what Im looking for, thanks!